Storage account and metastore (Databricks) in different data centers? Same region
I have a legacy storage account and databricks app deployed in Azure in the US EAST region. A new databricks app was deployed and migrated to in US EAST 2. However it points to the storage account in US EAST. I saw an increase in bandwidth price for data transfers in storage account. Could migrating my data to a US EAST 2 storage account help?
I see in the documentation that my metastore and and storage account should be in the same region. US EAST and US EAST 2 are in the same region but there was a significant increase in outgoing data. So, that is where my confusion lies.
I have looked at the cost analyses and see that the overall prices increased by over 200% on some days. The increase happened right when the migration was performed to the new Databricks environment, in US EAST 2.

These are two distinct Azure regions, not the same one. Hence the bandwidth charges.
Additional information: If you need more detailed charges/infomration based on your requirement you can reach Billing and Subscription team
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/options/
